# Symfony 2.8 - Attempted to call an undefined method named "hasOneMandatoryArgument" of class "Twig_Function_Method"

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

I updated PHP version 7.4.5 to 7.4.23 in Symfony 2.8 Framework.

After I am getting this error in Symfony vendor *"/vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php"*
Please help me here. for more information you can see screenshots also.

Error
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException]
Attempted to call an undefined method named "hasOneMandatoryArgument" of class "Twig_Function_Method".

[image]

$test->hasOneMandatoryArgument function call in vendor file(/vendor/twig/twig/src/ExpressionParser.php)
[image]

Comment: Anyone can help me here for i am getting this error after the update PHP version update in PHP framework Symfony 2.8.54.

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: Ok @I_love_vegetables.